# How do I find the first non-NA vector element without using built-in functions?

Tags: r, vector, na

For instance, I have a vector like this

```
x <- c(NA, NA, NA, 12, NA)
```

I want R to print the first non-NA element (12) **without using which or downloading packages**. I guess I should make a condition that `is.na(x) = FALSE` but I don't know how.

Comment: It would help to know *why* you want to avoid `which`.

Comment: Everything in R is a function (or a data structure). You can't use R without built-in functions.

Comment: I guess this is a homework, and by built-in they meant to avoid functions like "which", "na.omit" etc. Maybe using "forloop check if it is na, then print" is the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here are couple of ways -

```
#1.
na.omit(x)[1]
#[1] 12

#2.
x[!is.na(x)][1]
#[1] 12
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answers Ronak.  Even tho this looks like a 'do my homework' question, it's still handy for those of us using stackoverflow-search as a quick reference.